# Adding background image to list activity created using setlistadapter withpout a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to add the background and change the colors of an activity didnt create a layout ... used setListAdapter in oncreate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use thin in `onCreate()`

`getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.background)`